# working with \noindent and \indent

Tags: lists, indentation

How can I write a text with this style? Between the `\section` and the text, I want to place some bullets with smaller font sizes. Please note the no-indent bullets and the indentation of the first line of paragraph.

I have wrote this but there is no indentation at the first paragraph.

```
\section{The Section}
\noindent
    \begin{itemize}
      \item \textit{good}
      \item \textit{bad}
    \end{itemize}
\indent In this section....
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, notice that you don't have a paragraph break after the `itemize` environment, therefore there will be no indentation no matter whether you use `\indent` or not.

The first thing to fix is to add a paragraph there:

```
\section{The Section}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{good}
\item \textit{bad}
\end{itemize}

In this section....
```

[image: first]

Now, you get indentation but it's probably not what you wanted.  You may not like that the bullets are also indented.  This is the default style for `itemize`.  If you want to change it, the easiest way is probably to use the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{The Section}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\parindent]
\item \textit{good}
\item \textit{bad}
\end{itemize}

In this section....
\end{document}
```

[image: second]

This looks almost the same as your (Word, I presume?) document, except that the bullet itself is not left-aligned with the margin.  If you want that as well (I advise against it), you need some more tweaking:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{The Section}
\hrule\vskip 6pt
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\parindent, labelwidth=\parindent, labelsep=0pt, align=left]
\item \textit{good}
\item \textit{bad}
\end{itemize}

In this section....
\end{document}
```

[image: third]

but notice that the section number does not look exactly aligned with the left margin either.